# Why does an LED ceiling fixture glow even when switched off?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

I've just installed an LED ceiling fixture, and it glows even when switched off. I'd estimate it as about 5-10% of the switched-on intensity.

The answers I've found here on DIY.SE to similar questions revolve around the switch being a smart switch, or an illuminated switch, or a dimmer, or a motion sensor, and thus passing just enough current through to light the LEDs. As far as I can tell, my switch is none of those. But I replaced it with a new one, just in case. The glow is still present.

The glow even happens when the switch is removed from the circuit and left as an open circuit. (The switch is on the neutral side -- perhaps because it is an old house (~1915).) The only way I've gotten the glow not to happen is to **not** connect the ground from the fixture to the ceiling box. And I know that's not a good solution.

I've heard that good LED fixtures have circuitry in them to prevent this glow in the event of a small amount of residual current, such as from induction, but that cheap models can leave out that feature. This fixture is a standard brand from a big-box home improvement store. And it is ETL listed. So I don't expect it is a design flaw, but I've also reached out to the manufacturer for guidance.

Another Q&A indicated that LED fixtures controlled by 3-way switches can exhibit this glow. This isn't a 3-way switched circuit.

Hot-to-ground and hot-to-neutral in the ceiling junction box both measure in the 119 V to 120 V range.

The glow is continuous, not temporary. When I have the ground disconnected, the switched-off glow fades rather quickly to zero over about ten seconds. (This seems to be proper behavior for LED fixtures.) But when the ground is connected, it glows indefinitely -- at least 12 hours.

[image: Ceiling junction box]

There are three inlets in use. East, south, and west. It's all cloth-covered, so I can't differentiate by color. There is one wire that runs straight through without interruption from east to west. I think this is neutral based on no hit from a non-contact voltage detector.

Then there is another wire that enters from the east, and is spliced inside the box in a Y. One branch of the Y is a short pigtail that the hot from the fixture gets nutted to. (This is the leftmost wire nut in the photo.) The other branch exits the box to the west. This is hot, regardless of the position of the wall switch, based on the non-contact voltage detector.

There is a third wire coming into the box from the west. This is what the neutral from the fixture gets nutted to, and it behaves as if it is the switched-neutral coming back from the wall switch. (This is the rightmost wire nut in the photo.)

That same pair of nuts also connected a hot/neutral that leaves the box to the south, but the wires that go south don't seem to feed to anything that I can find. I've left them disconnected and capped and I haven't yet found anything in the house that is without power. (These are the two wire nuts in the lower center of the photo.)

I've white-taped what I've found to be neutral, and black-taped what I've found to be hot.

And a better-lit closeup of the inside of the junction box:

[image: closeup of the junction box contents]

Have I erred in ruling out the things I've ruled out? What else might be causing the glow?

### Update:

The vendor thinks it is a driver issue. They are sending a replacement. Stay tuned!

Comment: I haven't heard of even older homes switching the neutral instead of the hot. I think that's where the problem is. I'm sure one of our experts here will let you know for sure. When the switch is off current from the hot may be leaking into the ground. Sounds dangerous.

Comment: Is it continuous or does it fade over time - did you just test for just a few seconds or for several minutes or longer?

Comment: @Ack Continuous. When I have the ground disconnected, the switched-off glow fades rather quickly to zero over about ten seconds. But when the ground is connected, it glows indefinitely. Hours and hours.

Comment: Ok, that eliminates my idea. But then, the LED is receiving power. It involves the ground wire at the switch and not a completed circuit via the hot and neutral. I wonder if the switch is after the light, and there is some small bleed through the old fixture making it's way to the switch and is completed via the ground. It would take very little power to light an LED at 5%

Comment: Any way you can move the switch to the *hot* wire instead of neutral?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Not that I can see. I'd have to tear up a wall and a ceiling. It's pretty old, and it sure doesn't feel like the existing (cloth-covered) wiring will let me use it to pull new.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. There should only be 2 legal configurations: switch between panel and light or a switch loop (panel -> light -> switch). If it is between panel and light, you have hot (passing through), neutral, switched neutral - swap the wires and you get neutral passing through, hot, switched hot. If it is a switch loop, you should have a similar setup *at the light fixture* and be able to swap wires there to make the switch loop on hot instead of neutral. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'm probably just not grasping how the ceiling junction box is configured. I'll have to draw a diagram, but I'll start with a description. There are three inlets in use. East, south, and west. It's all cloth-covered, so I can't differentiate by color. (Maybe dirty=neutral and really-dirty=hot. :-) ) There is one wire that runs straight through without interruption from east to west. I think this is neutral based on no hit from a non-contact voltage detector. Then there is another wire that enters from the east, ... (continued in part 2)

Comment: (part 2) ... is spliced inside the box in a Y. One branch of the Y is a short pigtail that the hot from the fixture gets nutted to. The other branch exits the box to the west. This is hot, regardless of the position of the wall switch, based on the non-contact voltage detector. There is a third wire coming into the box from the west. This is what the neutral from the fixture gets nutted to, and it behaves as if it is the switched-neutral coming back from the wall switch. That same pair of nuts also connected a hot/neutral that leaves the box to the south, but ... (continued in part 3)

Comment: Right now a bit tired and did not read all the comments but you said switched neutral but only 1 switch. This has never been legal but a switch leg may have a hot on a white wire very common for decades. There is a configuration called a California 3way way that was legal at one time many decades back that did switch the neutral. The most common problem today is electronic switches or lighted switches causing LED’s to glow. The model of the fixture and type of switch is needed to be sure. Several times I have found lighted switch handles on single switches to be the cause, check this out.

Comment: (part 3) ... the wires that go south don't seem to feed to anything that I can find. I've left them disconnected and capped and I haven't yet found anything in the house that is without power. I could disassemble the splice (inside the cloth-wrapping) and see whether east or west is "upstream".

Comment: @EdBeal I basing my "switched neutral" conclusion on measured voltage, not on wire color. But I could still be getting it wrong. It's not an electronic or lighted switch. The fixture is a Jordan, by Good Earth. And the switch (I put in a brand new one during all of this) is a Hubbell single-pole.

Comment: @EdBeal -- your tiredness is showing -- the switched-neutral 3-way config you're looking for is a *Carter* 3-way.  (California 3-way switches don't touch the neutral, but they do use 3-way switches in a somewhat odd configuration, which has benefits and drawbacks.)

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the ceiling box please?

Comment: That’s what they called it in the San Francesco Bay Area during my apprenticeship in the Bay Area. Sorry not tired and this has been referenced on this site even though not legal for decades. Sorry that you are ignorant of this the fact of the matter that there were no wire colors in the early knob and tube days only left and right.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I've posted two photos of the box, and added the description that started in the comments to the question itself.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a video from Steve Mould I've seen recently - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uEmX5XClPY

Comment: @agweber That's a nice video. I don't think it applies in my case, because my LED fixture is not a low-end one. But they still might have cut some corners. I've reached out to the manufacturer for their input.